# Advice on total page size

Tags: html, image, size

I'm developing a very graphical website where images are a very important part of the site. In my firsts attempts the average page size is between 1.5 MB - 2.5 MB which I think is too much, but I would like to hear some advice on a reasonable top limit for a website.

Some considerations:

- Our target public is from all Spain, this means not everybody will have a fiber connection, many of them will have 10 MB ADSL connection, and some of them will have 3MB ADSL connection
- It's not a primary target, but owners want website to be available also on smartphones (although images are more important than smartphone accesibility)

What's your opinion? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe it or not, as average page size has exploded over the last few years, the average page size sits pretty squarely in that range.

http://httparchive.org/trends.php

I wouldn't worry too much about it, but definitely do everything you can to minify and optimize whatever code you have on the site. If your page needs a lot of images, it needs a lot of images.